# Does a user still keeps his earned bounty when his answer is deleted

Tags: support, bounties, deleted-answers

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304640/skamah-one) has deleted [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091283/keydown-event-not-firing/17184899#17184899) on the question [KeyDown event not firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091283/keydown-event-not-firing) that was awarded the bounty.

Is it correct that he still earned the bounty? He has not gained any reputation for the answer. But the bounty is still listed in his [earned bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304640/skamah-one?tab=bounties&sort=earned).

Comment: Well, that all smells to high heaven...

Comment: It wasn't deleted by the owner, it was deleted from within the Low Quality review queue. Since there is no delete event whatsoever on the post itself, guess the author keep all the reputation.

Comment: Caching.  (I don't see it in the earned bounties anymore.)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd he has not gained any reputation for the answer

Comment: @JonEricson for me its still there. I think you have not enough reputation to see deleted answers

Comment: It's still there for 10K users who can see deleted posts. Anyway can't know for sure if he kept the points or not but you found possible sock puppets, see what happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17092970/447356).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and Jehof: Makes sense.  Please ignore my babble.